# How to configure and access `$app->params['uploadPath']` in Yii2

Tags: yii2

1. I had created

   ```
   namespace common\components;
   use yii\base\BootstrapInterface;

   class Bootstrap implements BootstrapInterface
   {
       public function bootstrap($app)
       {
           // Here you can refer to Application object through $app variable
           $app->params['uploadPath'] = $app->basePath . '/uploads/';
           $app->params['uploadUrl'] => $app->urlManager->baseUrl . '/uploads/';
       }
   }
   ```

2.

```
    'bootstrap' => [
        ...
        'common\components\Bootstrap',
    ];
```

How to access  `$app->params['uploadPath']` in my controllers and views.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use BootstrapInterface if you want to access application params. You can simply call:

```
\Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'];
```

And you can set params in application configuration under `params` key.

Comment: I had used like this Yii::$app->params['uploadPath']; But its not worked for me. Is it a problem of  BootstrapInterface I had implemented or I had like Yii::$app->params['uploadPath']; intsead \Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'];

Comment: Include it in bootstrap section in application config: Actually where it is? I had done it in common/config/main-local.php

Comment: It's `Yii` if you added `use Yii` for the class otherwise it's `\Yii`. Just add `uploadPath` in configuration instead of bootstrapping this value.

Comment: Many Thanks. Done with this.